# Python: Learning classes, missing position argument in a list of classes

Tags: python, list, class

I am really new to Python, and I'm having difficulty with classes. I created a class Pet with name and type attributes.

```
class Pet:
def __init__(self, name, type):
    self.name = name
    self.type = type

def getName(self):
    return self.name

def getType(self):
    return self.type

def setName(self, name):
    self.name = name

def setType(self, type):
    self.type = type

def print(self):
    print("{} is a {}".format(self.name, self.type))
```

I created instances? of this class and appending them to a list.

```
listPets = []

pet1 = Pet("Hobo", "dog")
pet2 = Pet("Pal", "dog")
pet3 = Pet("Meow", "cat")

listPets.append(pet1)
listPets.append(pet2)
listPets.append(pet3)
```

My main goal is to print the name of the pets that are dogs.

```
for p in listPets:
if Pet.getType() == "dog":
    print(p.getName())
```

I get a TypeError with getType() missing 1 positional argument: 'self'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling `p.getType()`

`p` is the instance of the class, not `Pet`

Comment: Thank you so much. So from what I understand, because  p just the index of the list, we need to refer to the index which are the instances I called earlier. Basically, I guess I should not be calling my class like that but the instances of it?

Comment: `p` is referring to each element of the array. You want to check if the current _instance_ has a type of 'dog', not the whole class. So yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `p` variable for items in `listPets` then you should use `p` in the conditional statement too.

Replace, `if Pet.getType() == "dog":` with `if p.getType() == "dog":`

Since `Pet` is not an instance of class, when you call any method of class for `Pet` it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Class is like a special type. When you create a class, you are essentially creating a type that have some specific functions attached to it. Now, you can make variables of this type (object) and do stuff with it. So, when you want to do something with your variable (object here) you use your variable not the typename (e.g. `int + int`). To make it a bit more clear, `list` is a class. Say, you declare a list `l = [1,2]` and now append 3 to this list. You would write `l.append(3)` not `list.append(3)`. That was the error in your code, `Pet.getType()`. Your variable is `p`, so, you have to call by `p` as `p.getType()`.